# Joomla Cache Control After User Login/Logout

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, cache, global-configuration

If i set cache setting to **Progressive** or **Conservative** in global configuration setting page, it gives problem for users.

Content that

> *should only visible to logged in user*

will be shown if once user log-In and log-Out and **vise-verse**. How to stop this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If I rightly remember, there was some issues with the Progressive and Conservative caching that Joomla provides. Do bare in mind that Joomla's page caching only caches content and not assets, so if it's things like images, JS/CSS files you wish to do this for, then I would suggest a plugin such as JCE-Optimize

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the cache. If I understand your question correctly it might be the browser itself. According to the W3 spec, a browser's back button is not supposed to revalidate, it's simply supposed to show the page the way it was. More and more that is becoming the default behavior for browsers, meaning you have to use other options when coding your page in the first place.

http://256.com/gray/docs/rfc2616/13.html#13.13